# SQLite - TimeStamp to Date

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, timestamp

I am trying to convert a timestamp to date in SQLite.

But it give me always `Null` back, I try many solution I find out, but any solution works for me

Here is my request : 
[image]

Thats my SQL script, if you want to try:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointments (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    fromDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    toDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(200),
    type VARCHAR(50)
);

Insert INTO Appointments ( fromDateTime, toDateTime, name, description ) VALUES
('21/03/2020 15:00:00', '21/03/2020 16:00:00', 'Test', 'Test Description'), 
('22/03/2020 15:00:00', '22/03/2020 16:00:00', 'Test 2', 'Test 2 Description'),    
('22/03/2020 16:00:00', '22/03/2020 17:00:00', 'Test 2', 'Test 2 Description'),    
('22/03/2020 17:00:00', '22/03/2020 18:00:00', 'Test 2', 'Test 2 Description'),           
('21/03/2020 00:00:00', '25/03/2020 23:59:59', 'Test', 'Test Description'),      
('27/03/2020 08:00:00', '21/03/2020 12:00:00', 'Test', 'Test Description'),
('02/03/2020 08:00:00', '10/03/2020 12:00:00', 'Joelle', 'Test Joelle');
```

Comment: Change the format of your dates to: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @forpas comment, SQLite does not have a `TIMESTAMP` data type, so when you insert values into your `fromDateTime` and `toDateTime` column they are converted to one of SQLite's [5 data storage classes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): `NULL`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, `TEXT`, `BLOB`. Since there is no error on `INSERT`, this gives the impression that SQLite has recognised the value as a timestamp, when in fact the value has just been treated as `TEXT`. Now to use those values in any of SQLite's [Date and Time](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions they must either be an `ISO-8601` compatible string, the word `now`, or a number (interpreted as either a Julian day number or a Unix timestamp dependent on the context). So, you need to change your times to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format i.e.

```
Insert INTO Appointments ( fromDateTime, toDateTime, name, description ) VALUES
('2020-03-21 15:00:00', '2020-03-21 16:00:00', 'Test', 'Test Description'), 
('2020-03-22 15:00:00', '2020-03-22 16:00:00', 'Test 2', 'Test 2 Description'),    
('2020-03-22 16:00:00', '2020-03-22 17:00:00', 'Test 2', 'Test 2 Description'),    
('2020-03-22 17:00:00', '2020-03-22 18:00:00', 'Test 2', 'Test 2 Description'),           
('2020-03-21 00:00:00', '2020-03-25 23:59:59', 'Test', 'Test Description'),      
('2020-03-27 08:00:00', '2020-03-21 12:00:00', 'Test', 'Test Description'),
('2020-03-02 08:00:00', '2020-03-10 12:00:00', 'Joelle', 'Test Joelle');
```

Note that `datetime` is simply called with the column as a parameter and returns the string in an ISO-8601 format. To get `YYYY-MM-DD` format you need to use `strftime` as well. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT strftime('%d - %m - %Y', fromDateTime) AS y,
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d', fromDateTime) AS x
FROM Appointments
```

And the output:

```
y               x
21 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-21
22 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-22
22 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-22
22 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-22
21 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-21
27 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-27
02 - 03 - 2020  2020-03-02
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7be1f2c2cc05e20d3a9933716a1a91c8)